# JPanel Crossing Data Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have 1 JFrame while 3 JPanel inside it. In JPanel 1, it contains some JTextArea (Linkedlist of TextArea). JPanel 2 contains JTree. JPanel 3 contains JLabel.

Each time i press enter key in JTextArea, JPanel 1 will add a new JTextArea. Each new Text Area add, JPanel 2 (JTree) will add new node. Every TextArea have unique name. If we focus to any text area, JPanel 3 will display name of that text area with JLabel.

My question is, how can i change other componenet outside of JPanel 1? Most of my code inside in JPanel 1. I've already done with adding new text area. I'm using JPanel just only for make my work easier to look.

I've try to search other post and other resource. But, i still dont get what i want.

I'm using AbstractAction method. Here my state now:

```
Action enter = new AbstractAction() {
    //add new text area
};
```

I want be like this:

```
Action enter = new AbstractAction() {
    //add new text area
    //add node in JTree in JPanel 2
    //change text of JLabel in JPanel 3 
};
```

I hope this is clear for all of you

Comment: Try and devise some kind of model or models, that provide some kind listener callback mechanism, so interested parties can be notified of changes.  Pass these models around to all the components that need them...or simplify your design...

Comment: instead of unique names for jtextarea a array of text area / if you dont know the size then a List of jtextarea would be easier to handel

Comment: just a assumption : do u want the textarea say password to be displayed only after username textarea then u could make the rest invissible untill the previous is empty

Comment: @SrinathGanesh No. I just want to know how to change text in JLabel in JPanel 3 and add new node in JTree in JPanel 2 each i press enter key in JPanel 1. For making new JTextArea (im using Linkedlist of JTextArea), i need long code because it contain other function that cannot be replace. So, thats why i say too complicated. Btw, sorry for mKorbel. Im not try to post something that ambiguity. :(

Comment: I have not tried such a thing personally but , if each panel is a seperate class which has textfiled as a variable then the setter method must do that job . if no seterate class then every thing depends on the program flow

Comment: dont forget to refresh the panel after dynamic adding . (dont remmeber exact method name must be validate) use panelObject.validate()

Comment: My text are use AbstractAction `Action enter = new AbstractAction() {//add new text area};` My question is: how to make this: `Action enter = new AbstractAction() {//add new text area //add node in JTree in JPanel 2 //change text of JLabel in JPanel 3 };` I hope this is my best explanation :D

Comment: I've edit my question. Hope that will be better for explain what i want :)

Comment: What @MadProgrammer said is still best solution to your problem. Have a look at [Model-view-controller architecture](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html) if you get stuck.

Comment: *"Most of my code inside in JPanel 1"*  That suggests the code `extends JPanel`.  The code probably should not be extending anything and keeping the logic central..

Comment: @AndrewThompson i'm not exactly understand what are you mean. Do you mean my code not in JPanel 1? JPanel 1 have code to produce a new text area each time i press enter key while text cursor on one of them.

Comment: @atomman Actually, i dont understand what MadProgrammer mean until u give me that link..hahaha. But, i still dont get why you say that is the best solution. I think MVC just a method. Actually, i'm not a profesional programmer. Maybe that is the reason why i dont understand what you want to tell me. :(